# How do I get the default view for the Android Device Monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, automation, appium

I'm using the Android Studio 2.3.1 and wanted to access the Device Monitor to find the Elements without going through the code. I was able to do it until I accidentally closed a window and then to get that back I tried going through a lot of options. I want to go back to the default view. I uninstalled and re-installed and still the same case. Any one knows anything about it? Thank you.

[The Current Android Device Monitor Screen I'm on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xgxvu.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset all your ADM view click on reset perespective as the image shown below:

[image]